# DES: How to find the Inverse of the Initial Permutation?

Tags: des, permutation

I am doing a DES problem by hand and I want to know how you calculate the inverse of the initial permutation. I know what the permutation is, but how do you find it based off the given initial permutation?

Comment: Make a table of all possible $(i,P(i))$. Then sort by the second value (i.e. $P(i)$). This new table can be read as $(i,P^{-1}(i))$. Expected run-time: $O(2^n\cdot n)$ for an n-bit permutation

Comment: i, being what eactly?

Comment: $i$ being a bit string taking all possible inputs to the permutation function. This means for an n-bit permutation $0\leq i\leq2^{n}-1$.

Comment: So for instance, the initial permutation for DES is a 64 bit permutation. Would that not be ridiculous to do all i for 0 <= i <= 2^64-1? I am trying to get this wrapped around my head so thank you for you time.

Comment: This is feasible (although very costly). The easier approach would be to just consider the bit permutation used by DES which is a 6-bit permutation (mapping bit 0 to bit 58, bit 1 to bit 50, ...). [See Wikipedia for more data.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material)

Comment: Alright. I'm still very confused, but thank you for your help. I'll try and see if I can understand it. Just not sure how you're mapping. Probably thinking to much into this.

Comment: Could you possible give a simple example of what youre saying. I sort of get it but the 6 bits part is confusing me. Like for instance, can you show me what you mean with a some portion of the initial permutation.

Answer (score 4):

The inverse of the Initial Permutation (IP) of DES is the Final Permutation (FP) (in the Standard (NIST FIPS 46-3) FP is called "IP-1").  Number the 64 bits of the input to IP from 1 to 64.  Subject them to IP, so that the 1st 8 bits of the output of IP are bits { 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2 } etc. of the input.  Renumber (not reorder) the bits of the output of IP from 1 to 64.  Treat that as the input to FP.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan, the permutation IP is fixed so it is a table of only 64 entries, mapping the $i$-th position to the $P(i)$th position. Each entry $i$ (and $P(i)$) of the table is in the range $1,\ldots,64,$ so 6 bits are enough to represent each, but a byte can also be used.